# Python - class initializing issue

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

I'm very new into python and I'm trying to write simple genetic algorithm.

I have occured some problem with `__init__()`

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import random

class Genotype:

def __init__(self):
    self.name = ChCreator.names(self)
    self.fitness = ChCreator.fitness(self)

def mutation(self, m_prob):
    fitness = self.fitness
    if np.random.rand() < m_prob:
        _mutation = random.randint(0, 6)
        fitness = list(fitness)
        if fitness[_mutation] == '0':
            fitness[_mutation] = '1'
        else:
            fitness[_mutation] = '0'
    return ''.join(fitness)


class ChCreator:

ids = []
id = 1

def names(self):

    if ChCreator.id not in ChCreator.ids:
        ChCreator.ids.append(ChCreator.id)
        ChCreator.id += 1
        return 'ch' + str(ChCreator.id-1)

def fitness(self):
    return ''.join(random.choice('01') for _ in range(7))
```

As you can see for initializing self.name and self.fitness in Genotype im calling method from other class. Problem starts when I want to call Genotype.mutation() - instead of reffering to declared fitness value, its creating new one which is pretty obvious but i can't solve that.
Could anyone help me? I want to have a constant fitness value after creating Geontype object.

Comment: Passing an object of one class as the instance argument to another class's methods isn't a great idea. The fact that neither of `ChCreator's` methods even *use* `self` is evidence they should be static methods, if not simply functions using global variables.

Comment: My goal was creating many Genotype instances with various fitness values and ordered names so thats why i did it like this. I think i'll have to reword the code.